# How to add a control character inside a string executed by the execute command?

Tags: vimscript, register

I would like to have a mapping that opens a buffer with all the lines containing the word under the cursor.

I know such a mapping already exists in vanilla vim in normal mode `[I`.
But I don't like the output, the controls to move seem limited and I don't know how to edit it like a normal buffer.

I've come up with the following code:

```
function! LinesWithWordUnderCursor()

    " Clear register a
    let @a=""
    " Save cursor position
    let save_cursor = getcurpos()

    " Copy all the lines containing the word under cursor with format :
    " line number <space> line <CR>
    "
    " Resulting command :
    " g/{cword}/let @a = @a . line('.') . ' ' . getline('.') . '\r'

    execute "g/" . expand("<cword>") . "/let @a = @a . line('.') . ' ' . getline('.') . '\r'"

    " Put the cursor back where it was
    call setpos('.', save_cursor)
    " Open a new tab
    tabnew
    " Set buffer as temporary
    setlocal buftype=nofile noswapfile nobuflisted bufhidden=wipe nomodified
    " Paste register a
    put =@a

endfunction

nnoremap [I :<c-u>call LinesWithWordUnderCursor()<cr>
```

The function appends all the lines inside the register `a`.
I would like the following formatting :

*{the line number} {a tab character} {the line} {a newline character}*

The function works, but I don't know how to insert a control character like a tab or a newline on each copied line.
The command responsible for copying and formatting a line is:

```
execute "g/" . expand("<cword>") . "/let @a = @a . line('.') . ' ' . getline('.') . '\r'"
```

I've tried adding `\t` and `\n` in different ways (escaping the double quotes, using single quotes, using the `string()` function ...), but it always ends with an error or with undesirable single quote characters.

I'm trying to build a global command by concatenating a few strings and then execute it with `execute`.

At the end of the concatenation, `execute` should execute something like this :

```
g/{word under cursor}/let @a = @a . line('.') . "\t" . getline('.') . "\n"
```

For the moment I use a litteral space instead of a tab character, and a carriage return (`\r`) instead of a newline (which produces a weird output with the caret notation `^M` at the end of every line).

How can I modify the concatenation of strings executed by the `execute` command so that it integrates a tab character instead of a space and a newline character instead of a carriage return ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You command looks like follow without the `:execute`:

```
:g/pat/let @a.= line('.') . "\t" . getline('.') . "\n"
```

Adding in the `:execute` means you need to quote things correctly. The real trick is to use single quote. Also properly escape your single quotes or switching to double quotes.

```
 :execute 'g/' . expand('<cword>') . '/let @a.= line(".") . "\t" . getline(".") . "\n"'
```

For more help see:

```
:h expr-string
:h literal-string
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `\t`, you can capture a control character by first typing `CTRL-v` followed by the character you want. For sake of this example, let's say that `<TAB>` means "press the tab key", and `<RETURN>` means "press the return key".

To capture a tab character in your function definition: `CTRL-v<TAB>`. To capture a newline: `CTRL-v<RETURN>`.